# Image is not getting on the right side

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mOMQ.png)

Expecting Above Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSoZK.jpg)

Getting this Output.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="images-division">
            <img src="./assets/images/coding.jpg" class="image-one">
            <img src="./assets/images/webdev.jpg" class="image-two"/>
            <img src="./assets/images/piano.jpg" class="image-three"/>
            <img src="./assets/images/book.jpg" class="image-four"/>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS Part

```
.image-one {
    width: 50%;
}

.image-two {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 389px;
}

.image-three {
    width: 50%;
}

.image-four {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwAnk.jpg)

so first two images were positioned correctly, but these two aren't
Also when I am zooming out browser they get into same line but image size get decreased

Comment: use flex box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using float:right, we can put all images float:left.
Also you can style the images same class and same height to get better look.

```
.image-one, .image-two, .image-three , .image-four {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Another way can be using flex;

```
.images-division{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.image-one, .image-two, .image-three , .image-four {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Vote for me :))